# Eclipse:Dynamic Web Project Is it Mandatory to include OJDBC.jar file in WEB-INF?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jdbc

Recently While I was doing a Dynamic web project,I forgot to include OJDBC.jar in the WEB-INF folder.But the code ran file without showing any Class Not Found Exception.But when my friend did the same,Class not found exception was shown.Then when he included the OJDBC.jar in the WEB-INF folder,the code ran fine.I am not able to understand why this is the case.Is it not mandatory to include OJDBC file in WEB-INF folder?And we both used Apache Tomcat Server.[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot,I experimented by not including OJDBC.jar in the WEB-INF folder.The code ran fine.Please tell me why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Eclipse builds the context's classpath joining libraries from several locations:

- Of corse, the `<tomcat_home>\lib\*.jar` files.
- The `<project>\WEB-INF\lib\*.jar` files.
- ... and also the **deployment assembly** entries (within the project's properties).

Check out every one of these and compare with your partner ones.

Comment: yeah OJDBC.jar is there in my <tomcat_home>folder.So is this the reason why?Also I am using Tomcat v8 where as my friend's version is v7.

Comment: The actual reason is that you have the ojdbc.jar in the tomcat_home/lib folder, yes. Deploying the same application to different Tomcat versions (7 and 8) is probabily nothing to do with class location problems.